# Determining When a Package First Appeared in the PyPI Index using BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, package, pypi

I'm working on a project where I need to find out the initial release date of a package on the PyPI index. I came across the `bigquery-public-data.pypi.distribution_metadata` public dataset on BigQuery. From my understanding, there's a field called `upload_time` in this dataset that might indicate the upload timestamp of a package.

Can anyone confirm if the `upload_time` field refers to the time when a package was first uploaded to the PyPI index?

For reference, I found details about the PyPI BigQuery dataset here: PyPI bigquery dataset.
https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/bigquery-datasets.html

But PyPI website does not mention anything about the table metadata description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table `bigquery-public-data.pypi.distribution_metadata`, the upload_time field represents the date and time the specific version of the package was uploaded.

For example,

[image]

From the above picture, we can see that the ‘google-cloud-bigquery’ version 0.20.0 upload date is  `2016-09-29`  which means the first version  0.20.0  of the ‘google-cloud-bigquery’ package was released on `2016-09-29`.  You can confirm this by checking the release history from the [official Pypi documentation.](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/0.20.0/#history)